# NgModel clear values on tab change?

Tags: angular

I have this input :

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control-full" placeholder="" [ngModel]="addressDetails?.zipCode" name="zipCode">
```

And i have two tabs, and when i change tab and return my values from zip code is being empty. Any suggestion how can i fix that?

I populate input by selecting one address from grid

```
    getAddressDetails(address) {
         if (this.addressDetailForm) {
            this.addressDetailForm.addressDetails = address;
        }
}
```

Comment: Consider saving the data.. maybe in a common service

Comment: How do you handle your tabs ? Do they change the URL or is it like bootstrap's tabs ?

Comment: they dont change url, its something like bootsrap

Comment: *'something like bootsrap'*?

Comment: im using primeng

Comment: Component inside tab (PrimeNG) will be destroy when you change tab. So you need to store it some where as `Common Service` , `Call API` or you can use ngrx/store (redux).

Comment: i have in ngInit to call service so if it destroy component why not call it again in ngInit?

Answer (score 0):

Your data is cleared probably because the compoenent which is in your tab gets destroyed. You did not specify what your "two tabs" are. So we can;t really help you with that for now. If you are using some component for your tabs there might be an option to prevent destroying the content. If you are using the URL to decide which tab has to be open, you will have to save the data in a service.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, you are populating your form each time you render this component but you are not saving your data, right?

This means that:

1. You populate your input with `addressDetails?.zipCode` that you retrieve from somewhere.
2. You then go to another tab and that component probably gets destroyed.
3. You return to form component and you retrieve again `addressDetails?.zipCode` overwritting your previous value.

My suggestion would be:

- Save your `addressDetails` data *(Form data in general)* in an Object that you know it doesn't get destroyed nor overwritten.
- Save your form data in a Service as soon as you leave your current component. This way when you return to it you can get data from that service, if is empty, you get data from Server, API, or whatever...